# How to send true or false if there's data in child table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, one-to-many

I have 2 tables that are related (parent-child), if there's any attachment added there will be an entry in the child table. We are fetching data using a stored procedure. I want to return true or false for every record. I have tried the following,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testname] 
(
    @Date DATE
)
AS

BEGIN
    
    SELECT TOP 10000
        s.column1
        , s.column2
        , s.column3
        , s.column4
        , s.column5, ....,
        , c.ParentID
    FROM 
        ParentTable p WITH(NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN SomeOtherTable s WITH(NOLOCK) ON
            p.ID = s.ID
        LEFT JOIN ChildTable c WITH(NOLOCK) ON
            p.ID = c.ParentID

    WHERE 
        p.CreatedDate >= @Date
    ORDER BY 
        p.CreatedDate DESC;

END
```

This one is working fine, but is returning the value only for records which have a value in the child table. Also, the relation between parent-child is one-to-many. This query is also returning the same record from the parent table for every record in the child table, and it is only returning those records which have an entry in both tables, which shouldn't be the case.

Can anybody help me with how to do this? I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but [putting `NOLOCK` everywhere is a bad habit](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere), and it's never too late to get out of it.

Comment: If it is treating tables `s` or `c` as an `INNER JOIN`, it is likely you have used them in the `WHERE` clause.  A `LEFT JOIN` table changes to `INNER JOIN` if you use it anywhere in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `exists` in a `case expression`.

```
Select <columns from parent table>,
  case when exists (select * from ChildTable c where c.ParentId=p.Id) then 1 else 0 end as HasChild
from Parent t
```

I was about to also suggest a more compact form using `iif()` then noted you had tagged SQL Server 2008... so I won't!

Comment: Ah yes I misplaced a closing bracket, I think that's what you're referring to? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is obviously contrived to illustrate the issue, and not the actual query.  So this answer also uses contrived data to illustrate what it sounds like you want.

It seems like you are trying to return the record from `ParentTable` with a true or false to indicate if there is a record in the child table.

1. You cannot `LEFT JOIN` at child table and then use the child table in the `WHERE` clause.  Doing so changes it to an `INNER JOIN`.
2. If you have a one-to-many relationship and join the two tables together, you will see the parent record as many times as there are child records.

There are several ways to see if there is a child record.  These are but two solutions.  You should look at the query plan of whatever you choose to use, so that you can make sure it is optimized against your dataset.

```
create table #parent (id int, value varchar(10))
create table #child (id int, parent_id int, value varchar(10))

create clustered index pk_parent on #parent (id)
create clustered index pk_child on #child (id)
create index idx_fk_child_parent on #child (parent_id)

insert into #parent values (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')
insert into #child values (1, 1, 'red'), (2, 3, 'blue'), (3, 3, 'green')

/* correlated sub-query solution */
select p.*, has_child = cast(1 as bit)
from   #parent p
where  exists (select 1 from #child c where p.id = c.parent_id)

union all

select p.*, has_child = cast(0 as bit)
from   #parent p
where  not exists (select 1 from #child c where p.id = c.parent_id)
order by p.id

/* nested sub-query solution */
select p.*, has_child = isnull(c.has_child, 0)
from   #parent p
       left join (
         select distinct parent_id, has_child = cast(1 as bit)
         from   #child
       ) c on p.id = c.parent_id
order by p.id

drop table #parent, #child
```

Both of these return the following:

```
id          value      has_child
----------- ---------- ---------
1           one        1
2           two        0
3           three      1
```

The `correlated sub-query` is the most obvious and simply sets `has_child` to true or false based on `exists` or `not exists`.  The `sub-query` solution is less obvious.  If a record exists, `has_child` will be `1`.  If a record does not exists, `has_child` will be `NULL`.

The `sub-query` performs better than the `correlated sub-query` because it only has to hit the tables 1 time each, instead of two times.  But I don't know how many records you actually have in your tables or how they are indexed.  So look at the query plan for both and see where you can optimize.

I added indexes that would approximate the indexes in a real database.  The cost of the `correlated sub-query` is 4 times higher than the `sub-query` solution.  Other solutions likely exist that would perform even better.

The `nested sub-query solution` has very good stats, the CPU is especially low in the inner query.

Hopefully this helps and answers your questions.

Comment: There were actually 3 questions in the OP.  1) why doesn't `LEFT JOIN` include records that are only in the parent table, 2) why does the query return a parent record for each child that exists, and 3) how can I get an accurate true/false to indicate if there is a child record.  I answered all 3 of those questions, and included a dataset to illustrate the solution and provide query plan stats.  I fail to see why someone would down-vote.